# Hudson CI server and git plugin: Why do I get ERROR: Nothing to do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, hudson

I'm trying to get hudson setup on a Debian server to build a rails project, and its constantly falling over at the first hurdle.

I get the following sequence of messages everytime I try to run a build:

```
Started by user anonymous
Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/hudson/jobs/myproject/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@2d61100c
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision caced2eba6ed6ba8a5bbcccbedb531bc28702f66 (origin/master)
Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/hudson/jobs/myproject/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@2d61100c
GitAPI created
Wiping out workspace first
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository origin
$ /usr/bin/git clone -o origin git@code.myproject.com:/myproject.git /var/lib/hudson/jobs/myproject/workspace
Fetching upstream changes from git@code.myproject.com:/myproject.git
[workspace] $ /usr/bin/git fetch -t git@code.myproject.com:/myproject.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[workspace] $ /usr/bin/git ls-tree HEAD
[workspace] $ /usr/bin/git rev-parse origin/master
ERROR: Nothing to do
Finished: FAILURE
```

My config is as follows:

url of repository: git@code.myproject.com:/myproject.git

repository : origin

branch to build: origin/master (have tried with just master, and with the default)

I have seen this error mentioned elsewhere online, but I have already configured my app in a way that should prevent the error....

So I have no idea why this is happening. Can anyone lend an insight?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing anything about Ruby, but... Well, what would you like Hudson to do? In the Build section of the Configure screen for that job, do you have anything defined? There are options in the Add Build Step... pulldown. (I admit it's not obvious that you need to do this in the Hudson UI!) If you were in the Java universe, you might do an Ant build or something.

Answer (score 0):

Is your branch on origin?

When I had this error it turned out I had added my branch to Hudson but I never added it to origin. I was working with a local branch, not a remote one. I put my branch on origin and then Hudson was able to build.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to explicitly checkout master in my build steps. I expected that I would automatically be on master, but by poking around I realized that this was not so (even though "branched to build" was set to master. Maybe that helps?

Also, are you using RVM? If so you may need to source your ~/.bashrc file in a build step (I think). Can you show the build steps you are using (if any)?